# Trouble returning a vector array c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am fairly new to C++ so sorry if this is a simple question!

I am currently making a Sudoku solver. Each cell has a candidate list which is a set of values that it could possibly be. The candidate decreases by deleting values that are on the same row, column and block, till eventually there is only one single value in the candidate list, and that will be the cell's new solved value.

I have that part working, however another way the cell may be solved is by 'hidden values'. Hidden values are found by comparing the cell's candidate list, with the candidate lists from the cell's row, column or block. If the current cell has a value in it's candidate list which can not be found in any of the others, then that must be the cell's  solved value.

What I am having trouble with is returning the cell's candidate list so I can return it with others.

I have a cell class, and a cell group class. The cell group is basically a row, column or block. Each group contains 9 cells.

In the **cell group class** I have the following method:

```
 int CellGroup::checkHiddenSinglesRow(Cell * cell) const
{
int candidateList[] = { cell->getCandidateList() }; //not returning correctly

 int hiddenSingle = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    Cell *cells = m_cells[i];
    bool found = cells->SearchCandidateList(value);
    if (found == true) {

        hiddenSingle = hiddenSingle + 1;
    }
}
return hiddenSingle;
```

}

The search candidate method basically goes through a cells candidate list and returns true if it has found the value, **in the cell class**:

```
 bool Cell::SearchCandidateList(int value) {
bool found;
auto it = find(m_candidateList.begin(), m_candidateList.end(), value);
if (it != m_candidateList.end()) {
    found = true;
}
else {
    found = false;
}
return found;
```

}

And this is the method I used to return the current cells candidate list, in **the cell class**:

```
   int Cell::getCandidateList(void) const
 {
for (auto i = m_candidateList.begin(); i != m_candidateList.end(); ++i) {
    int j;
    j = *i;
    return j;
}


}
```

The getCandidateList is returning 1 which may be the first value in the candidate list.
It may be useful to return the list as an array so i can compare the values inside it, however I am unsure how to implement this.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thanks Lucy

Comment: Why don't you return the *actual* vector instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return vector like that:

```
std::vector<int> Cell::getCandidateList() const
{
    return m_candidateList;
}
```